# Create new workbook from existing worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

How to copy the entire worksheet from a workbook and save it as new workbook  to a specific directory with the customized filename(I am trying to pick the filename from on of the cells in the worksheet. The sheet that I need to copy has few merged cells too.

```
Sub CopyItOver()
Dim fname As String
Dim fpath As String
Dim NewBook As Workbook
Dim name as String 

fpath = "C:\Users\..\"
fname = "List" & name & ".xlsm"
name =   Range("c3").Value 

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Generator").Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)

    If Dir(fpath & "\" & fname) <> "" Then
    MsgBox "File " & fpath & "\" & fname & " already exists"
      Else
    NewBook.SaveAs FileName:=fpath & "\" & fname
End If

End Sub
```

When I run this it, give me Subscript out of range  error in this line

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Generator").Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
```

Comment: In this case your challenge is determining what part of that statement is giving you the error. It could be `Activeworkbook.Sheets("Generator")` or it could be `NewBook.Sheets(1)`. When the program stops, choose to `Debug` the VBA and in the immediate window type `Debug.Print Activeworkbook.Sheets("Generator").Name` and `Debug.Print NewBook.Sheets(1).Name` and see what you get. It's likely that one of those actions will give you the error and show you what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you try it like this:

- Check to see if *Generator* exists before progressing
- If you use .Copy then the worksheet is automatically copied to a new workbook (so you don't need to add a new book first)

*code*

```
Sub CopyItOver()
Dim fname As String
Dim fpath As String
Dim name As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

fpath = "C:\Users\..\"
fname = "List" & name & ".xlsm"
name = Range("c3").Value

On Error Resume Next
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Generator")
On Error GoTo 0

If ws Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "sheet doesn't exist"
   Exit Sub
End If

If Dir(fpath & "\" & fname) = vbNullString Then
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Generator").Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fpath & "\" & fname
Else
     MsgBox "File " & fpath & "\" & fname & " already exists"
End If

End Sub
```